# Refactor a section of query-building to the Eloquent model and make it chainable with other Builders

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, eloquent-relationship

I want to refactor the `withCount` part from the following code to reuse it and make the controller shorter.

```php
class GroupController extends Controller
{
    public function show(int $group = 1)
    {
        return Group::where('id', '>', 0)  // to simulate starting the query with some builder
            ->withCount([
                "requests",
                'requests AS requests_count_pending' => function ($query) {
                    $query->where('state', 'pending');
                },
                'requests AS requests_count_accepted' => function ($query) {
                    $query->where('state', 'accepted');
                },
                'requests AS requests_count_refused' => function ($query) {
                    $query->where('state', 'refused');
                }
            ])
            ->find($group);
    }
}
```

**I want to build the query with the following syntax:**

```php
$group = Group::where('id', '>', 0)
    ::withCountRequests()
    ->find($group);
```

---

---

### What I tried (Patch)

```
public static function withRequestsCount()
{
    return self::withCount([
        "requests",
        'requests AS requests_count_pending' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('state', 'pending');
        },
        'requests AS requests_count_accepted' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('state', 'accepted');
        },
        'requests AS requests_count_refused' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('state', 'refused');
        }
    ]);
}
```

```
public function show(int $group = 1)
{
    return Group::withRequestsCount()
        ->where('id', '>', 0)
        ->find($group);
}
```

The solution works only when I call the static method first. But I want to chain it fluently like any other `Builder`

---

---

### Reproducing

```
php .\artisan make:model -mcrf Group
php .\artisan make:model -mcrf Request
```

#### Migrations

```php
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('groups', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

```php
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('requests', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->set('state', ['pending', 'accepted', 'refused']);
        $table->foreignId('group_id');
    });
}
```

#### Models

```
class Group extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function requests()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Request::class);
    }
}
```

#### Factory and seeder

```php
class RequestFactory extends Factory
{
    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            'group_id' => 1,
            'state' => $this->faker->randomElement(['pending', 'accepted', 'refused']),
        ];
    }
}
```

```php
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('groups')->insertOrIgnore(['id' => 1]);

        Request::factory(50)->create();
    }
}
```

### Route

```php
Route::get('the_group', [GroupController::class, 'show']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a query scope. It's similar to what you tried with the `withRequestCount` function.

```php
public static function scopeWithRequestsCount($query)
{
    return $query->withCount([
        "requests",
        'requests AS requests_count_pending' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('state', 'pending');
        },
        'requests AS requests_count_accepted' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('state', 'accepted');
        },
        'requests AS requests_count_refused' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('state', 'refused');
        }
    ]);
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#local-scopes

Comment: I thought that scopes were limited to applying `where` statements. I didn't think that I may expand their usage to relationships. Thank you (#upvoted I may accept the answer in a little while. I'm just still intrested in seeing more possibilities)

Comment: I feel that the reproducing part is useless now XD

Comment: Scopes have access to every builder method but should return the same builder instance. (so other methods can be then chained to it) or void